# CakePhp edit form not sending post data

Tags: php, cakephp

Edit form not sending data to controller via post, its working perfectly fine on my local host, create and delete functions are also performing good on my  c panel server, but there is an issue on edit form.
Tried defining action in form create as well. 
There seems no issue with the code as its working great on my local xampp server, no issues with database connection as i can create and delete entries as well on c panel server

```
echo $this->Form->create('Entry', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'div' => 'form-group',
        'wrapInput' => false,
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'method'=> 'post',

    ),
));
```

Comment: Can You show edit action from controller? Maybe You should use `post` and `put` together

Comment: Please share your edit action code.

Comment: The problem has been solved, there was some security feature installed on hosting server, restricting the edit command, disabling that solved the issue.